# Is it possible to get a menu map of Blender?

Tags: interface

I'd like to look at and compare the menu trees in different editors and modes. This would look something like:

- Workspace: Layout

  - Editor: 3D Viewport

    - Mode: Object

      - Menu: Add

        - Selection: Mesh

          - Selection: Plane
          - Selection: Cube
          - ...
        - Selection: Curve

          - etc.
        - etc.
      - etc.
    - etc.
  - etc.
- etc.

At the very least, that information is certainly contained in the code, but I'm not sure where to look for it. The manual gives listings of some menus, but not all of them. Also, the manual is not reliable because it has errors. So I'd like to get a listing of menus exported directly from the software.

Is that possible?

Is there a way to get those data about Blender?

Comment: You want to "look at and compare"... I'm sorry but I'm voting to close this question as it is too localized and I do not think there is a benefit for the community in answering this question as it is not an issue that needs to be solved. And just for example, this is the menu tree of the _Geometry Node Editor_ (from Blender 3.6.2 I think): [node_tree_GN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh2dX.jpg), I doubt that having those for multiple editors will be very useful, definitely not as a resource to look up something... but maybe someone else will know how you get the information.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann - That map is perfect, within its context. Can you tell me where you got it, and can I get it in text?

Comment: This is just a collection of screenshots I did a while ago for someone who was complaining that there is no option to see the **complete** menu hierarchy expanded when using _Add_ (Shift+A) in _Geometry Nodes_. I wanted to show him what menu he would have to choose from each time it opened fully expanded.

Comment: I still don't see a general benefit to this to make it a relevant question for this site. It is just like these shortcut sheets where people try to somehow fit every Blender shortcut in one overview. It is much too much to learn by looking at it or scrolling through it, the most frequently used shortcuts you'll learn quicker by working with them. And having to look for everything else which you do not use so often you can do very quickly inside Blender by just using the search function in the editor you are working in. Whereas in the _Add_ menus I simply learn where to look for things.

Comment: I don't know what's useful to others. I geek out on large assemblages of data and observing patterns, which can yield a level of system understanding. It was the basis of my PhD in physics and a large part of my career since then. I was thinking of doing exactly the kind of assembly of menu images that you produced to show your friend how useless it would be. Doing that across the whole menu system would probably take more effort than this would be worth, so I was asking to see if there might be an easier way to get the data. I can understand that it may be of little interest to others.

Comment: If you were stuck in a project and needed this solution to go on working, I would understand it is relevant. But just for "fun" it misses a point in the help section about how to ask a good question: _"Make it relevant to others: We like to help as many people at a time as we can. Make it clear how your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us will be interested in your question and willing to look into it."_ But although this is preferable, it is not mandatory to ask questions here. I only see that nobody has an answer yet and it is not viewed many times.

Comment: While I agree with Gordon to some degree, I think it could be beneficial to some people to know how to get a list of a menu's items in different context, I reckon it's possible to do with Python? It doesn't have to be explained specifically for @NewSites's case, it could be shown as a generic method, and any reader can use that knowledge to do whatever.

Comment: @L0Lock - Do you know how to get Python to generate that map? I don't know Python, but I see that Blender has a Python console, so if I had some code, I could run it. Could you post code for that as an answer to this question?